# Entity Framework cannot mark single property as modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 and what I am trying to do is to get entry by primary key and update only one property in the entry by Entity Framework.

My code is shown below:

```
    private static void UpdateByEntry()
    {
        using (var context = new EntityFrameworkTestDBContext())
        {
            var request = new Request
            {
                requestId = 1
            };

            var entry = context.Entry(request);

            entry.Property(x => x.updateDate).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(x => x.updateDate).OriginalValue = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine("state of updateDate {0}", entry.Property(x => x.updateDate).IsModified);
            Console.WriteLine("state of entry {0}", entry.State);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The result of this program is：

```
state of updateDate False
state of entry Detached
```

and the column `updateDate` is NOT updated after `context.saveChanges()`.

I checked msdn in this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592677(v=vs.113).aspx . Their sample code is shown below and I cannot see any difference.

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1); 

    context.Entry(blog).Property(u => u.Name).IsModified = true; 

    // Use a string for the property name 
    context.Entry(blog).Property("Name").IsModified = true; 
}
```

It is said that

> Marking a property as modified forces an update to be send to the database for the property when SaveChanges is called even if the current value of the property is the same as its original value.

But I marked as modified and property is not updated in the database.

My question is: why is `isModfified` of property `updateDate` is false even if I already changed it as `true`.

How can I update only one property in an entry?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `State` of your entire `Request` object is "Detached" since you just created it and is not yet attached to the context (in contrast to the MSDN example which fetches an already attached object). You need to add it first using something like `context.Requests.Add(request)`

Comment: @haim770 I tried `entry.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;` and it works. But the problem is, if I do this, every property state is `modified` and I manually set every other property's status as false. Is this the best practice?

Comment: Use `EntityState.Attached`, not `EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: I would suggest the same as @haim770.

Comment: @GertArnold There is no state called `Attached` in `EntityState`. I tried `unchanged` and it works as I expect, thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, slip of the, erm... keyboard.